# Is it possible to trigger a compile time error when the value for asp-page tag helper is incorrect?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

In ASP.NET Core projects with Razor Pages, is it possible to configure something that would generate compile time errors or at least warnings if the path to another page defined as the value for asp-page (and related attributes) is incorrect?

For example:

`<a class="nav-link" asp-page="/Admin/User/Index">Users</a>`

Imagine there's a typo here and the value should've been `/Admin/Users/Index` instead. As far as I can see this is silently ignored and the href is simply not generated, which kind of sucks.

It would be awesome to have an error triggered during build/compile time since the razor template is compiled anyway.

Comment: Can you use the `nameof()` operator somehow to reference the `Index()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to configure something that would generate compile time errors or at least warnings if the path to another page defined as the value for asp-page (and related attributes) is incorrect?

There is no way to do that according to the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/f5b6039add50ea84ddb151cd6daf5207119dc116/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/AnchorTagHelper.cs#L244).

The tag helper call the `Generator.GeneratePageLink` method to generate the link.The compiler could not call this method in compile time.